# How can I determine which payments have been cleared from pending state?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been setting up the Stripe Connect onboarding flow. When creating a connected account, we have two states for the payments that have been made: "Available to pay out" and "Available soon", which are "Available" and "Pending" when using the Stripe API. I have set up the manual payout system as I want to control the payout process myself. But I have a problem there. I need to know exactly what payments, that have been made, were cleared for the "Available" state. Does Stripe provide such info for some objects: charges/transfers/payments? How can I determine that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing transactions included is only available for Automatic Payout. Stripe has [a Doc on how to List balance transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#charges-in-payout) on Automatic Payout. They also have [Payout reconciliation report](https://reconciliation).

On another hand, there is no transactions relation on Manual Payout unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

> On another hand, there is no transactions relation on Manual Payout unfortunately.

That's not completely true.
Supposing you only ever create manual payouts for the full available balance, then you can infer which balance_transactions constitute that Payout.
Likewise, you can infer which balance_transactions constitute the available balance.

It's all about the `created` timestamp of your Payout, and the `available_on` timestamp of your balance_transaction.

Let's consider this series of transactions:
-balance_transaction, created 10-01, available_on T+3
-balance_transaction, created 10-05, available_on T+3
-Payout, created 10-06
-balance_transaction, created 10-06, available_on T+3
-balance_transaction, created 10-10, available_on T+3

Your payments coming in have a delay between the `created` time and `available_on` time, however your Payouts don't (if they're manual).

Therefore, you can infer which balance_transactions constitute your available balance as being any balance_transaction where the `available_on` time is greater than the last Payout's `created` time.

In the above example, although one of the balance_transactions was created before the Payout, it's `available_on` time comes after, so it would actually be included in the available balance still.